# Find collision between laser and grid of circular obstacles

Tags: modular-arithmetic, analytic-geometry

Assume you have a regular grid of circular obstacles, defined by the equation:

$$\left[\textrm{mod}\left(x-x_{0}+\frac{d_{x}}{2},d_{x}\right)-\frac{d_{x}}{2}\right]^{2}+\left[\textrm{mod}\left(y-y_{0}+\frac{d_{y}}{2},d_{y}\right)-\frac{d_{y}}{2}\right]^{2}\le R^{2}\\R\leq\frac{1}{2}\min\left\{ d_{x},d_{y}\right\}$$

Where $d_{x,y}$ are the distances between the circles in each axis, $\left(x_0,y_0\right)$ is the center of a specific circle, and $R$ is the radues of the circles.
Assume also that in such a grid, we shoot a laser ray from location $\mathbf{r_0}$ with direction $\theta$ (I made a simple Desmos plot of the situation [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tufynwzck5)).

[image: A Desmos plot of the situation described]

**In this setup, is there a closed-form way to find the location of the first hit of the ray with the obstacles?**

I searched and found many answers to questions similar to this one, but couldn't find an exact match, nor could I convert their answer to fit my question. If you successfully find an existing answer, this will suffice too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So treat the circles as lattice points ?

Comment: You may, if it gives any useful insight. Just remember that they have radius $R$

Comment: I think a closed form expression is very unlikely. Will pseudocode for a search be useful? The continued fraction expansion of the slope might help, since it should tell you when the ray comes close to a lattice point.

Comment: @EthanBolker As long the search is efficient, I think this may be enough. Apparently this question is a lot more complicated then I thought...

Comment: I think it could be useful to imagine the problem as a laser in a room of mirrors with quarter circles on it's corners. All we need to do then is find how many times it bounces off the walls before it hits a circle

Answer (score 1):

Another view at the problem is the following. For simplicity assume $\mathbf{r}_0 = (0,0)$ and $d_x=d_y=1$, $x_0=y_0=0$ (The ray actually starts in a circle, however, we will disregard this hit later). This is only for reasons of presentation and I believe that the idea generalizes to the general setting that you presented.

Let $r_x,r_y$ be the unit-length vector, which is *perpendicular* to your ray. Now, projecting the circles onto this vector, will give line segments on that vector. If such a line segment includes the origin, the ray will hit a circle. The circles have centers $t_x,t_y \in \mathbb{N}$, whose projection onto the line is $t_xr_x + t_yr_y$. The condition for a ray to hit a circle with center $r_x,r_y$ eventually is thus
$$ (t_xr_x+t_yr_y)^2 \leq R^2.  $$
Since you want to find the *first* hit of the ray with a circle, the problem that you are looking to solve is
$$ \min_{t_x,t_y \in \mathbb{N}} t_x^2+t_y^2~\text{ s.t. } (t_xr_x+t_yr_y)^2 \leq R^2.$$
This is a non-linear integer optimization problem, which you could try and solve with standard solvers. You might want to take care that you only consider those $t_x,t_y$ that are actually in the correct direction (the projection also gives you solutions which are behind your ray).

Comment: This is a really nice way to look at the problem! I don't know if optimization is the solution I was looking for (I think it would be easier and faster to just simulate the movement of the laser and find the first hit point), but +50 points for style.

Comment: I'm glad you appreciate it - I'll come forward, if I have an idea how to solve this problem efficiently! It's a nice problem by the way.